# Different results for decodeBase64 in Glassfish and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption, glassfish, base64

I have a value that i encode with special characters, then encode it again using base64, my development environment is the standard uses Netbeans glassfish server, but site is hosted on Tomcat server, I seem to get different results for exactly the same decryption code/function, it works perfect in netbeans, but on tomcat fails, making my special character decode code fail as characters are not the same

```
String key = enc_key;

// Create key and cipher
Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

// decrypt the text
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
strDecrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted.getBytes())));
```

Any suggestions :-( ?

Comment: In short: Use `String.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` and `String(arrayOfBytes,Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`, otherwise you'll never know which charset it used

Comment: @Pablo: As of Java 7, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: Ouch! True, this is what happens when you are stuck to "corporative standards" (AKA "Java 6 works, don't touch")

Comment: Added the encoding, but this is what i get on Netbeans glassfish **Z,Â¡EÃ°Â¥Ã•[â€™Ã½Â¿ÃˆÂ¼jÃ„Â°Ã¸Â»4[Ã?IÂ¿Ã˜Å¡+Y'':Ã¸{@Ã¢VÅ½â€°        <â€œIÃ dÃ©â€“+0i)Â«oÃ–**
and in tomcat i get which is right **Z,Â¡EÃ°Â¥Ã•[ â€™Ã½Â¿ÃˆÂ¼jÃ„Â°Ã¸Â»4[Ã�IÂ¿Ã˜Å¡+Y'':Ã¸{@Ã¢VÅ½â€° <â€œIÃ dÃ©â€“+0i)Â«oÃ–** which is wrong :-( :-( why? why? why?
the question mark is represented wrongly

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `String(byte[])` constructor without specifying an encoding. Don't do that.

Likewise, don't call `String.getBytes()` without specifying the encoding, either. You're doing that twice in the code you've shown us - and my guess is that you did it when encrypting the data. *Always* specify the encoding you want to use.

Now we don't know which `Base64` class you're using, but I would personally try to find a method which accepts a `String` to decode to start with - Base64 is logically a `byte[] <==> String` conversion scheme, so in a decent API you'd have `String encode(byte[])` and `byte[] decode(String)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what encoding would you best suggest i use for special characters?

Comment: @Lappies: I would suggest using UTF-8 *everywhere*. Also be aware that there's really no such concept as "special characters" - any time you use that term, you should try to be more precise about what you're trying to represent.

Comment: Added the encoding, but this is what i get on Netbeans glassfish **Z,Â¡EÃ°Â¥Ã•[â€™Ã½Â¿ÃˆÂ¼jÃ„Â°Ã¸Â»4[Ã?IÂ¿Ã˜Å¡+Y'':Ã¸{@Ã¢VÅ½â€°        <â€œIÃ dÃ©â€“+0i)Â«oÃ–**
and in tomcat i get which is right **Z,Â¡EÃ°Â¥Ã•[ â€™Ã½Â¿ÃˆÂ¼jÃ„Â°Ã¸Â»4[Ã�IÂ¿Ã˜Å¡+Y'':Ã¸{@Ã¢VÅ½â€° <â€œIÃ dÃ©â€“+0i)Â«oÃ–** which is wrong :-( :-( why? why? why?
the question mark is represented wrongly

Comment: @Lappies: That looks like it's not text to start with. What is the data meant to represent? And have you fixed the *encrypting* part to specify the encoding too?

Comment: this is how the text encrypted looks like 123HGW457#-#7939#-#777, its then encrypted usisng cipher and a 128bit key

Comment: @Lappies: There are no non-ASCII characters in that... it sounds like the encryption/decryption possibly isn't working in this case. I suggest you follow the steps in http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/ to work out where things are actually going wrong.

Comment: Ok seem to have found the problem, its actually not encryption, but my encrypted value, via base64 has "+" characters, and when I use **request.getParameter("l")**, this charater is changed to an empty spaces? any idea why?

Comment: @Lappies: Yes, that's just url encoding. You should probably use a url-safe variant of base64.